# Pandas to_excel() writes zeroes as strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-excel

My code writes the Pandas dataframe to excel just fine.

Most of the data (numeric) is written as numeric in Excel which is good :-).
However all cells containing 0 are written as text, which is not :-(

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter(tidydatafile,
                      date_format='DD-MMM-YYYY',
                      datetime_format='DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS') as writer:
        tdf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=ttable, index = True, na_rep='')
```

Excel warns: Number stored as text
only for the zeroes

Is this a known bug of to_excel()

Is there any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

OK - sorry folks. Totally noob error.

The imported data sheet had errors in it. It was just a matter of wrapping int() around the cell reading code to change from string to integer :-)

`...append(int(cell.value))`